# validate empty variable regex

Tags: java, regex, variables, string

I have a regex scipt which validate a field variable for some extensions (pdf, doc, jpeg, jpg, and png). But sometimes, this field can be empty. I see on some topics that "^$" can solved my problem. I try a lot of combinaisons (cause I do not know regex) but it doesn't work. I give you my current code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String REGEX = "([^#@]+(\\.(?i)(pdf|doc|docx|jpeg|mp3|jpg|png))\$)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(field_Fichier1.getFileName());
return matcher.matches();
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not just check for empty string, and apply the regex check on a non-empty string?

Comment: The code is included in a validator, in the software BonitaBPM. I can't do (or I do not know how to do) a loop inside the validator. I already try to do it but no success. THat's why I try to do it all the need in the regex code.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Mine = doesn't work for empty field
//String REGEX = "([^#@]+(\\.(?i)(pdf|doc|docx|jpeg|mp3|jpg|png))\$)";

// Anubhava = doesn't work for empty field
//String REGEX = "([^#@]+(\\.(?i)(pdf|doc|docx|jpeg|mp3|jpg|png)))?";
//        or
//String REGEX = "([^#@]+(\\.(?i)(pdf|doc|docx|jpeg|mp3|jpg|png)))";

// Bohemian = can't be run = error: "Groovy:illegal string body character after dollar sign;"
String REGEX = "^$|([^#@]+(\\.(?i)(pdf|doc|docx|jpeg|mp3|jpg|png))\$)";
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I put this code on a groovy script... in bonitaBPM software if it can help

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `\$` in your regex. You can just make your whole regex optional to allow for empty string match:

```
String REGEX = "([^#@]+(\\.(?i)(pdf|doc|docx|jpeg|mp3|jpg|png)))?";
```

`?` in the end will make whole regex match optional thus allowing it match `""` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `^$|` to the front of your regex:

```
String REGEX = "^$|([^#@]+(\\.(?i)(pdf|doc|docx|jpeg|mp3|jpg|png))\$)";
```

Note that I haven't checked your existing regex - I'm assuming it works for non-blank input.